# Safari 5.1 (OS X Lion) Inspect Element / Web Inspector always pops up and is not docked to main window

Tags: macos, safari

Been using OS X 10.7 Lion since early developer previews and there is this bug (or feature that's not implemented). Clicking **Inspect Element/Web Inspector** of the Develop tools will always pop up the **Web Inspector** window. It used to be stuck or used to remember my preference and used it as default.

It is docked by default on Chrome and FireBug is well docked in Firefox and it was docked by default (or remember my settings) in Safari 5 on Snow Leopard.

Anyone faced this issue and have a fix?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, this is a strange change (bug?) introduced in 5.1, previous versions of Safari used to remember whether the inspector was toggled to be a standalone window or embedded in the bottom of the browser. Now it launches in a full standalone window every time regardless of its previous state. I haven't managed to find a fix yet, but I'm also annoyed by the new behavior of the inspector in 5.1.

Comment: For what it's worth, the current WebKit nightly build (July 25) exhibits the same Inspector behavior as Safari 5.1 on Lion, opening in a separate window every time. http://nightly.webkit.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819523/safari-web-inspector-showing-up-in-new-window-by-default ; this is a bug that has been reported and appears to be fixed in the nightlies.

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom left hand corner of the popup there is a little button that looks like a dark square with a white square in it. That button pops the inspector in and out.

Don't know if that will fix your problem but you can try

Comment: I'm actually aware of that, but it used to popped in by default on Snow Leopard or it used to remember if i wanted it to pop out or pop in as a default setting.

Comment: Sorry :/ thats all the help I got

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. But I prefer Web Inspector is docked to main windows as default.

Answer (score 0):

Since I actually like to use it as a separate window, it does not bother me that much. However, the thing that drives me to the edge of suicide is the change that AJAX requests are not logged if the Web Inspector is not open. My usual development workflow of testing the UI -> in case something is broken, open Web Inspector -> check what's happening has been completely broken -- now I need to open Web Inspector and try to repeat the bug. Grrh, why Apple why?